# Where's the Google Analytics 4.0 website traffic reports like Universal Analytics had?

Tags: google-analytics, traffic, reporting

I upgraded a website to the new Google Analytics 4, and it really is lacking the great reporting that the old Google Analytics (aka Universal Analytics) had. The old version had great reports for viewing website pageviews, top pages, etc. The new GA4 doesn't seem to have all the same reports, and the pageview numbers don't look to be reporting all the pageviews the website is recieving.

Does anyone know how to get the same reports the old Google Analytics had using the new Google Analytics 4?

Thanks!

Comment: thank you for that question! I have been myself in the same situation

Answer (score 4):

> Does anyone know how to get the same reports the old Google Analytics
> had using the new Google Analytics 4?

Short answer, you cant.
GA4 is departure from the "old style" Universal GA. Different api, different reporting etc.

If you wish to create a Universal Property, start the new property creation process and on the Property Settings page, select the Advanced options and turn on the Universal option, then save the settings.

[image]

Bare in mind, turning on the Universal property option for a GA4 property does not work to change the property type, you need to create the Universal Property when creating a new Property.

It will give you the option of creating both types of properties or just a Universal Property.

If you select to create both, you will then be able to access the Universal Property from the Property column drop down and access all the usual interface and settings for Universal GA.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh how I wanted this to work!  It appears this functionality is going to be gone permanently effective July 2023.  When attempting to follow these steps you receive "Universal Analytics properties will stop collecting data starting July 1, 2023. It’s recommended that you create a Google Analytics 4 property instead."